# How to upload local code to EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I wanna run my nodejs codes on Amazon EC2.

I use this code to test(using vi to code on 64-bit Amazon Linux)

```
var http = require('http');  
http.createServer(function (req, res) {  
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});  
  res.end('Hello World\n');  
}).listen(80);  
console.log('Server running at http://12.34.56.78/');
```

and It really works. 
But now how can I upload my local nodejs code (in my computer now)to amazon EC2, I use 64-bit Amazon Linux

Comment: Quick and dirty with scp: http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php (but the suggestion about using Git by @iuri is a better long term)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a unique way to achieve that task. You could use various approaches, each of them with its pro's and con's.

An easy solution would be to use a bare git repository in the server you want to upload the code to, and push your code to that remote repository. You could even [use git hooks](http://www.sitepoint.com/one-click-app-deployment-server-side-git-hooks/?utm_content=bufferdfacc&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer) to automate the deployment and *npm install* when pushing new code.

One thing I'd recommend you is that, as EC2 instance storage is volatile, you probably should automate the server setup & configuration using something like Opscode's Chef. Either that or implement some incremental backups for your EBS volumes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like fabric. http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/  I've found it very quick to get things done:

```
from fabric.api import put, run, task

def run_your_app():
    run("node js command to run your app")

@task
def put_your_file():
    put("localfilename", "remoteFilename")
    run_your_app();
```

Save this to 'fabfile.py' and then your run it from the command line:

```
fab -H <your hostname or ip> put_your_file
```

Also more on the fabric operations here:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/operations.html